# GDAL rasterizelayer function 's additive rasterizing option (add=True) is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterization, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to rasterize a set of polygons with integer features. Since I am very new using raster data as an initial step I am rasterizing the the polygon centroids first.

In the output array I want to see the aggregated values of the integer features. I found out in the documentation that setting "add=True" should work. But it is not working.
link to the documentation is here https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#RasterizeOptions

You can access my data here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uzQ6eZodQNN_Qzi1-G85-BaPvElU8KeS?usp=sharing

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon, MultiPoint
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from osgeo import gdal
import ogr
import logging
from rasterio.plot import show

fn_ras = 'Data/Vector_Data/sanfrancisco.tif'

fn_vec ="Data/Vector_Data/vec_cbg.shp"

### Read the base tif file -- from 
ras_ds = gdal.Open(fn_ras) 

geot = ras_ds.GetGeoTransform()

vec_ds = ogr.Open(fn_vec,0)

lyr = vec_ds.GetLayer() 

featureCount = lyr.GetFeatureCount()

print ("Number of features in {}: {}".format(os.path.basename(fn_vec),featureCount))

lyr.GetFeature(10).GetField('BlockGroup')



### CREATE THE TARGET RASTER

pixel_size = 0.01
source_srs = lyr.GetSpatialRef()

x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = (-122.63749999999999, -121.39250000000001, 36.902499999999996, 38.1375)


# Create the destination data source
x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)


### Change the geotransform
## the GT(2) and GT(4) coefficients are zero, 
## and the GT(1) is pixel width, and GT(5) is pixel height. 
## The (GT(0),GT(3)) position is the top left corner of the top left pixel of the raster.
# Create a new geomatrix for the image

geot= list(geot)
geot[0] = x_min
geot[3] = y_max
geot[1] = pixel_size
geot[5] = - pixel_size


# Create a new raster for the rasterized polygons 
drv_tiff = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")


target_ds = drv_tiff.Create('sf.tiff', x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.gdalconst.GDT_Float32)

target_ds.SetGeoTransform(geot)

target_ds.SetProjection(ras_ds.GetProjection())

##WHY IS THIS PRINTING OUT 0 ???

# Rasterize
gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr , options=["attribute=BlockGroup", 'allTouched=True',"add=True"])

# Read as array
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
##this returns none
array = band.ReadAsArray()

print(array.shape)
print(array.sum()) ## something WRONG

geometry = gpd.read_file(fn_vec)
df = geometry[(geometry.bounds['minx'] >= x_min) & 
         (geometry.bounds['maxx'] <= x_max) & 
         (geometry.bounds['miny'] >= y_min) &
         (geometry.bounds['maxy'] <= y_max) ]
print(len(df))    

print(df['BlockGroup'].sum())

print(df['BlockGroup'].max())

show(array)
```

I am double checking with the input sums and there is a huge difference. The values per geometry should be added to the corresponding cells. At least cells look ok by visual inspection.

I think add option is not working. But why?

[image]

Comment: Suggest you rasterize your polygons directly, not the centroids.

Comment: Thats making things much more complicated. I have to figure out the add function first. Some polygons (census block groups actually) are very large and their values are burned to all cells that has spatial correspondence. Add option is also not working. Ideally I would like a function to distribute the values to cells based on area and that maybe achievable with some preprocessing.  But 'add" option will keep being an issue in that case too.

Comment: Maybe I do not follow your workflow right but if you rasterize a point it will affect one pixel. Is that your aim?

Comment: ever find out why add=True is not working? I'm having the same issue